# Wildcard have same class then take first child of the css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

If some elements have a class with prefix and if the class is similar then I need to hide all classes except for the first one.

```
<span class="prefix-one">A</span>
<span class="prefix-two">B</span>
<span class="prefix-one">C</span>
<span class="prefix-three">D</span>
<span class="prefix-four">E</span>
<span class="prefix-one">F</span>
<span class="prefix-five">G</span>
```

Here `prefix-one` is repeated thrice. So I need to display only the first one.

And the result needs to be like

```
ABDEG
```

That is, I need to hide the repeated `span`.
I tried using some wildcard CSS selector like

```
<style>
  [class*="prefix-"]{
    display: none;
  }
  [class*="prefix-"]:first-child{
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

nothing works.
Is there is any possibility to select an element like this?

If there is nothing jQuery also acceptable. But I would like to have a solution with CSS or SCSS.

> NB: This one is only an example. The word after prefix- is dynamic. So hardcoding the class name is not possible. I can't add any specific class to them. The HTML is generated from some other way.

Comment: It's still working what is the problem here.

Comment: is your expected output `ABDEG` inside the first span?

Comment: @ArindamSarkar @Syed My expected output is `ABDEG` in each span. And need to hide the repeated one.

Comment: Add class .prefix to each span and style it with .prefix and .prefix:first-child

Comment: @Ponleu I have already mentioned that prefix- is dynamic and I can't add any specific class to them. The HTML is generated from some other way.

Comment: @Stackoverflow Before marking as duplicate make sure you have an idea about the question. The duplicated question didn't give a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

I provided solution with jquery.

```js
var text = "";

$('[class^="prefix-"]').each(function(){
  text += $(this).text()
});
var i=0;
$('[class^="prefix-"]').each(function(){
  if(i==0)
    $(this).css('display','block')  
    
  $(this).html(text);
  i++;
});
```

```css
[class*="prefix-"]{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="prefix-one">A</span>
<span class="prefix-two">B</span>
<span class="prefix-one">C</span>
<span class="prefix-three">D</span>
<span class="prefix-four">E</span>
<span class="prefix-one">F</span>
<span class="prefix-five">G</span>
```

Comment: I already mention that HTML is generated and it may have an image tag or a huge data inside the class. Maybe a slick slider which initializes on page load. We can switch the items to hidden using some other way. Using CSS or SCSS is a little bit better.